# Issue with defer and return in golang echo framework

Tags: go, echo

Help to understand, how I able to restart my echo framework but before returning the HTTP response?
The case is that I have *"Restart()"* function and it's working if use inside the script. But for now, I need to restart script, after the returing HTTP response.

I have tried to use "*defer*" for this, but receving the usage error.

```
defer global.Restart()
return echo_context.JSON(http.StatusOK, fmt.Print("Restart has been launched))
```

> Internal error. Please contact with support. Message: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

Will be great to hear any ideas, thanks.

My restart function is done like that :

```
func Restart(ConfigFile string) {

    self, err := os.Executable()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Sprintf("Application cannot be automatically restart. Please contact with support. Message %s", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    args := os.Args
    env := os.Environ()

    cmd := exec.Command(
        self,
        "--config",
        ConfigFile,
  )

    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Env = env

  err = cmd.Run()

    if err == nil {
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    syscall.Exec(self, args, env)
}
```

P.S. tried to use echo.Shutdown() - but... the start after shutdown is not supported

Comment: You need to provide a good bit more detail.  What does your `global.Restart()` function do?  It seems like you're trying to start the server again without it ever having shut down, which is causing it to attempt to rebind to an already bound address tuple, and that attempt is, predictably enough, failing.  But I'm making assumptions based on minimal information.  Please share more of your code and your use case - what is it that you are trying to accomplish?